# Best practice for managing dynamic allocated memory in C++

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm playing around with the Qt library to get a better understanding for OOP.
One thing I implemented is a QGraphicsView, which display's an image. Therefore, the data has to outlive the scope of the funtion it is "created" in, so I called it with the "new" operator. I know that the memory once allocated with "new" has to be deallocated with "delete", but that's not possible out of scope. So I figured (and this is where I did not find a clear answer unfortunately) I'll use a map to store the address of the memory to delete it when I load a new image. But is that good practice or even correct?

```
void myFunction()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(fileName);
    QPixmap scaledPixmap;
    if (!alloc_map.empty())
    {
        QGraphicsScene* test = alloc_map.at(0);
        delete test;
        alloc_map.clear();
    }
    
    scaledPixmap = pixmap.scaled(ui.graphicsView_UnprocessedImage->width(),   ui.graphicsView_UnprocessedImage->height(),
        Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    alloc_map.insert(std::pair<int, QGraphicsScene*>(0, scene));
    ui.graphicsView_UnprocessedImage->setScene(scene);
    ui.graphicsView_UnprocessedImage->scene()->addPixmap(scaledPixmap);
    ui.graphicsView_UnprocessedImage->show();
}
```

Comment: Smart pointers for when such thing is truly needed. Here a better design is to make it so that the value doesn't fall out of scope just use `QGraphicsScene scene;` Why recreate the scene here? You can `clear()` it and add the new pixmap, so you can for example set up the scene where you create the view.  (Also, scale the view to the image pixmap instead?)

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers if <X>  is "good practice" you're guaranteed to receive at least eleven different answers...

Comment: Qt is a mature and powerful framework, by all means go explore it, it lets you build terrific stuff. It might not be the first place to learn about "classic" OOP though, there's too much happening behind the scenes for that.

Answer (score 2):

Qt has its own way of dealing with memory with QObjects, (QGraphicsScene inherits QObject). You passed `this` as a parent, and we don't know which parent is referred to with `this`, but if the parent (`this`) outlives the QGraphicsScene you created you are fine. Because Qt will properly delete your QGraphicsScene when `this` gets deleted. Qt world is a bit more complex than C++ world and allocating new objects on the heap there is the way to go without dealing with their deletion. However don't forget to delete any memory you allocated outside of Qt's world. Happy coding :)

See : [Object Trees & Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html)

Edit: To go further and as a more general C++ advice, I'll add that your function is definitely a class method as you are allowed to use `this`. If you want to manage the memory by yourself within this class, then you should store this pointer as a class attribute. Then in any other method could you delete this pointer. Even better, if the object you allocate is supposed to live exactly the same amount of time as your class referenced to as `this` make it a non-pointer (plain `QGraphicsScene` instead of `QGraphicsScene*`) and initialize it as your class gets constructed and let the destruction automatically be handled by the compiler. But that's not always what you want with QObject-derived classes. Another powerfull C++ tool is to make use of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and allocate your pointer in the class constructor and delete it in the class destructor so that you still allocate it on the heap (if it's a large object or a large array for example - but for large arrays use `std::vector` really) and make sure you delete it properly no matter what.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I used the Mainwindow as a parent here. Unfortunately, it seems that object does not deallocate the memory used from the image before once you load a new image. Thats what brought me to use this map here.

Comment: @DBMC_y337 Could you edit your question with more context, then ? Like, when do you populate your map and which image are your refering to, as well as when and why do you want it deleted ? You shouldn't have to use an allocation map ever.

Comment: Before I used the map, I just created a QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene. Because of that, of course the old memory didnt get deallocated but every call of the function allocated new memory for a new image.

Comment: @DBMC_y337 Why didn't you just store the pointer itself as an attribute then instead of storing it in an intermediate map ? You can just delete your pointer before allocating the new one. The map looks like a useless container for your pointer. Just store the pointer itself.
With more details : 
Have an attribute in your class `QGraphicsScene* scene = nullptr;`, then remove all your map logic and replace the line where you allocate the new scene with :
`delete scene;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);`.